# is there a way to hide a column in rhandsontable when passing a dataframe

Tags: rhandsontable

I have a data frame that I am passing to a rhandsontable . Say the data frame has columns (A and B). In the display I want to format column B based on the values in column A , but I don't want to display column A. Is there a way to do that. I don't see column attribute in the rhandsontable.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The below code is what worked for me.  If you apply the filter before removing the column from the dataset, it should work.

```
output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
    hot <- df
    if(input$filter > 1) {
    hot <- hot[[hot$A %in% input$filter,]
     }
    hot<-hot[!A]
    rhandsontable(DF1)
 })
```